# Trouble understanding Queue's in Swift (async await)

Tags: swift, xcode, asynchronous, async-await

i'm reworking my coreData methods to use async and await at the moment, and still having problems understanding those queue's in Swift,
maybe you guys can help me out here..

The problem is, that i want to collect feedback (logComment) after each step processed inside the function "newUpdateMethod()"
and the only way that worked for me is to put that: "@MainActor" in front of the function

As far as i understood it, that means i force that function to run on the main Queue instead of a background queue where async jobs would run otherwise..
because of that main queue i am able to fill up the variable "logComment" along the way and return it to the VC who called it..
but i am not 100 sure, if this way is really necessary, there has to be another way achieving this...
i tried to put the logComment statements inside a DispatchQueue.main.sync block to talk to the main queue, but still:
"Mutation of captured var 'logComment' in concurrently-executing code"

my coreData methods

1. json fetch method

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class CoreDataInteraction {
//(...)
     func getRemoteData() async throws -> [RemoteData] {
        var remoteData = [RemoteData]()
        
        do {
            let url = URL(string: "***")!
            let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
            let (data, _) =  try await URLSession.shared.data(for: urlRequest)
            remoteData = try JSONDecoder().decode([RemoteData].self, from: data)
        }catch{
            let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "remoteData", withExtension: "json")    // use local data instead
            let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)
            let (data, _) =  try await URLSession.shared.data(for: urlRequest)
            remoteData = try JSONDecoder().decode([RemoteWire].self, from: data)
            
            DispatchQueue.main.sync { Logging.insertError(message: error.localizedDescription, location: "get json data") }
        }

        return remoteData
    }
```

2. update method

```
    @MainActor  // really necessary ?
    func newUpdateMethod(completion: @escaping (String?) -> Void){
        var logComment:String = ""
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        let request = RemoteData.fetchRequest() as NSFetchRequest<RemoteData>
        
        Task {
            do {
                // Step 1
                let jsonData = try await getRemoteData()
                    logComment = logComment + "\n Line 1"
                // Step 2
                var existingData = try context.fetch(request);
                    logComment = logComment + "\n Line 2"
                // Step 3 comparison..
                // ...
                    logComment = logComment + "\n Line 3"
                // Step 4 ...
                // continue . . .
                
                
            }
            completion(logComment)
        }
        
    }
}
```

Here's the VC function which calls that update method receiving the feedback and puts it into the UI

```
class SettingsVC: UIViewController {
//(...)
  @IBAction func updateButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        //MARK: NEW Update processing
        self.LoadingStart()
        myCoreData.newUpdateMethod() {(success) in
            self.LoadingStop()
            self.updateTextField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12.0)
            self.updateTextField.text = success
            self.updateButton.isEnabled = false
        }
    }

}
```

i found no other way besides @MAinActor to make this thing work..
there has to be a way to get the values of a variable out of that Task/do background queue, otherwise it is pretty useless in MY understanding
obviously i am missing something in my understanding here :/

Comment: Unrelated, but I'd advise against using `URLSession` when reading data from bundle. Just use `Data(contentsOf:)` when reading from your local file system.

Comment: I also wonder why you're still using completion handler code in `newUpdateMethod`. The whole idea of async-await is that it renders that pattern unnecessary.

Comment: I might advise checking out WWDC 2021 [Bring Core Data concurrency to Swift and SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10017/), if you haven't seen it.

Comment: thx @Rob i've just watched that video, the context.perform is not an option to me bc my app's target iOS version is 14..i kind a understand the topic but i'm still having problems, adopting this new syntax to my own project :(

Answer (score 0):

i think i kind a solved it..
take a look:

```
    func newUpdateMethod2() async -> String {
        var logComment:String = ""
        let context = await (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        let request = RemoteData.fetchRequest() as NSFetchRequest<RemoteData>
        
        let jsonData = try? await getRemoteData()
        guard jsonData != nil else {
            Logging.insertError(message: "error creating json source", location: "newUpdateMethod2")
            logComment = logComment + "⚠️  Error collecting json source"
            return logComment
        }
            
        var existingData = try? context.fetch(request)
        logComment = logComment + "\n Line 2(existing data count: \(existingData!.count))"
        
        return logComment
    }
```

and here's the calling part:

```
    @IBAction func updateButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        //MARK: NEW Update processing
        Task {
            do {
                self.LoadingStart()
                let feedback = await myCoreData.newUpdateMethod2()
                self.LoadingStop()
                self.updateTextField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12.0)
                self.updateTextField.text = feedback
                self.updateButton.isEnabled = false
                print("feedback = \(feedback)")
            }
        }
```

...no completion handlers anymore :)

i had to help myself with guard instead of catch, because i did not want to wrap all of the code inside a do {} statement again, and found no other way to use catch without do {}..
so guard is doing it's job (y)

i guess i figuered it out :) thx guys !